# Truncated mean javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mean

I have code that looks like:

```
$(function () {
    var a = 0,
        timeCff = 0, //Firefox
        timeSff = 0,
        $.get('test1.csv').done(function (data) {
            var i,
            lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/),
                line = lines[0].split(','),
                oS = line.indexOf('oS'),
                browName = line.indexOf('browName'),
                browVer = line.indexOf('browVer'),
                timeCanvas = line.indexOf('timeCanvas'),
                timeSvg = line.indexOf('timeSvg');
            for (i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                line = lines[i].split(',');
                if (line[browName] === 'Firefox') {
                    a++;
                    timeCff += parseFloat(line[timeCanvas], 10);
                    timeSff += parseFloat(line[timeSvg], 10);
                }
            }
            $('#osInfo1').html("Twoja średnia  to: " + timeC / a);
            $('#osInfo2').html("Twój sytem operacyjny to: " + timeS / a);
        });
});
```

And as we see i counts aritmethic mean. But i would like to count truncated mean to have better results. I searched with google for some help but couldnt find any solution. I think i need to use some arrays but i dont know how.

Does some have any idea how to do it or some usefull info?? Maybe there is some good libary for that??

Comment: at face value..use `parseInt()` instead of `parseFloat` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For truncated means you would discard the high and low samples, which you would do once for `timeCanvas` and once for `timeSvg`

You could sort the lines with a custom function

```
function sortByTimeCanvas(a,b)(
  return a[timeCanvas]- b[timeCanvas]
)
```

and then drop the highest and lowest entries with `slice`, and then find the mean.

Answer (score 1):

This takes 2 values:

(1) values (number array): an array of numbers from which to calculate the trimmed average

(2) trimPercent (number): a percent starting what percent of numbers you want to trim

For example:

```
trimmedAverage([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 20)
```

will remove 20% of numbers from the array, namely the highest and the lowest

The values array need not be sorted (as the function does that internally)

Here's a code snippet with the code:

```js
const trimmedAvg = (values, trimPercent) => {
  const sortedValues = values.sort()
  const trimCount = Math.floor(sortedValues.length * ((trimPercent / 2) * 0.01))
  const trimmedValues = sortedValues.slice(trimCount, sortedValues.length - trimCount)
  if (!trimmedValues.length) return null
  const sum = trimmedValues.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)
  return sum / trimmedValues.length
}

const arr = [100, 101, 102, 500, 103, 104, 105, 106, 1, 107, 108, 109, 110]

console.log(trimmedAvg(arr, 20))
```